# How come I can't download this webpage in python?

Tags: python, http, url, curl, download

**Please try this yourself :) !**

```
curl http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps?list=free
```

the result is:

```
    <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&amp;rpsnv=11&amp;checkda=1&amp;ct=1320735308&amp;rver=6.1.6195.0&amp;wp=MBI&amp;wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-US%2Fapps%3Flist%3Dfree&amp;lc=1033&amp;id=268289">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

or

```
def download(source_url):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)        
        agents = ['Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)','Microsoft Internet Explorer/4.0b1 (Windows 95)','Opera/8.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)']
        ree = urllib2.Request(source_url)
        ree.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(ree)
        htmlSource = resp.read()
        return htmlSource
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return ""

download('http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps?list=free')
```

the result is:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; URL=http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps?list=free"><script type="text/javascript">function OnBack(){}</script></head></html>
```

I want to download the actual source of the webpage.

Comment: It seems the page does a redirect depending on whether your logged into your Live account. Your scripts is not logged in to a Live account.

Comment: @Pengman go to http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps?list=free  on your browser. I just want this HTML code . How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it fails is because http://www.windowsphone.com attempts to set a cookie, which is checked on https://login.live.com which creates another cookie and redirects back to windowsphone.com if successful.

You should look into http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html

If you want to use curl, allow it to create a cookie-file like so:

```
curl -so /dev/null 'http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps?list=free' -c 'myCookieJar'
```

Run `more myCookieJar` in your shell and you'll see something like this:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.www.windowsphone.com   TRUE    /       FALSE   0       WPMSLSS SLSS=1
login.live.com  FALSE   /       FALSE   0       MSPRequ lt=1320738008&co=1&id=268289
```

Run (notice the -b option before 'myCookieJar'):

```
curl -so 'windowsphone.html' 'http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps?list=free' -b 'myCookieJar'
```

and you'll get the contents of the page in the file windowsphone.html as you see it in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Flesk really has the answer on this one (+1).

Another straight-forward way to debug HTTP connections is [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/), which is basically a powerful telnet utility.

So let's say you want to debug what's going on in your HTTP request:

```
$ nc www.windowsphone.com 80
GET /en-US/apps?list=free HTTP/1.0
Host: www.windowsphone.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)
```

That will send the request header to the server (you'll need to press the enter key **twice** to send).

After that, the server will respond:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1320745265&rver=6.1.6195.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-US%2Fapps%3Flist%3Dfree&lc=1033&id=268289
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: WPMSLSS=SLSS=1; domain=www.windowsphone.com; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Server: SN2CONXWWBA06
Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2011 09:41:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 337

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&amp;rpsnv=11&amp;checkda=1&amp;ct=1320745265&amp;rver=6.1.6195.0&amp;wp=MBI&amp;wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-US%2Fapps%3Flist%3Dfree&amp;lc=1033&amp;id=268289">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

So the server returns 302, which is the HTTP status code for redirect and thereby prompts the "browser" to open the URL passed in the Location-header.

Netcat is a great tool to debug and trace all kinds of network communication and helped me a lot when I wanted to dig a little deeper into the HTTP protocol.