# Using cURL to download a site's HTML source, but getting different file than intended

Tags: php, curl, http-referer, spoofing

I'm trying to use cURL and PHP to download the HTML source (as it appears in the browser) of [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/ea39f002-ac30-e011-854c-00237de2db9e). But instead of the actual source code, this is returned instead (a meta refresh link set to 0).

```
<html>
    <head><title>Object moved</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Object moved to <a href="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&amp;rpsnv=11&amp;checkda=1&amp;ct=1321044850&amp;rver=6.1.6195.0&amp;wp=MBI&amp;wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-US%2Fapps%2Fea39f002-ac30-e011-854c-00237de2db9e&amp;lc=1033&amp;id=268289">here</a>.
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to spoof the referral header to be the site, but it seems I'm doing it wrong. Code is below. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/ea39f002-ac30-e011-854c-00237de2db9e');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/ea39f002-ac30-e011-854c-00237de2db9e");

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I've got a feeling I answered this one before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046907/how-come-i-cant-download-this-webpage-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/ea39f002-ac30-e011-854c-00237de2db9e');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.windowsphone.com");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it. You need the follow location option to be set to true.

Answer (score 7):

Add the curl option to follow redirects:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

If it is a meta refresh and not an HTTP moved header, see:
[PHP: Can CURL follow meta redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820705/php-can-curl-follow-meta-redirects)

As mentioned by flesk, you may also need to store the cookies.

Comment: I'm writing the HTML returned to a separate file (to read from later). When I set FOLLOWLOCATION to true, the file became blank.

Comment: This works fine if the redirect is just in the headers. I just tested it with your code, and the page returns a 200 OK with a meta refresh tag. See my edit.

Comment: excellent, I'll check it out.

Sorry I'm new to all this HTTP/spoofing/cURL

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the referrer but that you need to enable cookies for it to work.

Try something like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

You have to query the page twice. First allow redirects to get the cookie from login.live.com, then query again with the cookie set.