# PHP Curl / File Get Contents not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to do the following

```
$url = "http://halo-video.com/drama/ha";
$data = file_get_contents($url);

echo $data;
```

it give me a blank page or a 500 internal error, I tried load the site with my computer, and its load fine.

Comment: Check your error logs to determine the error and report back.

Comment: I tried print and it show a 500 internal error, but the site load fine with my com

Comment: @user1777711 There's obviously something wrong with the `kissanime.com` domain because I replaced the URL with Google's and it worked fine (code).

Comment: @Fred-ii- But i can access it using my computer but not by php curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although reason could be different but my code (similar to yours) works fine so just append these lines into yours at appropriate places,

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; nl; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7";
                 curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                    curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
                    curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Comment: The response should not be Object move to here, if you access using your computer, the response is different.

Comment: FMI please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099919/using-curl-to-download-a-sites-html-source-but-getting-different-file-than-int

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Ok, this was bugging me so figured out a fix.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://kissanime.com/Anime/Karneval');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'myuseragent'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.test.com");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

This code works and fixed the redirect errors I was getting.  Happy content grabbing.

Comment: But the original page content is not Object moved to here. If you try access by your window its different.

Answer (score 0):

Use file() instead of file_get_contents()

```
$url = "http://kissanime.com/Anime/Karneval";
$data = file($url);

echo htmlspecialchars($data);
```